# How do I get the active profile in a build.gradle task for a Spring Boot Project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

No matter what I do, I cannot get the active profile in a build.gradle task when I try:

```
println property('spring.profiles.active')
```

I'm running the project by running:

```
./gradlew bootRun --args='--spring.profiles.active=dev'
```

I want to be able to distinguish between dev and prod in build.gradle

Comment: Just copy/pasted/executed your command and I clearly see that `The following 1 profile is active: "dev"`. Where you are trying to read this property?

Comment: I want to view it in the build.gradle file